# How can we implement Observable.flatMapCompletable?

Tags: java, rx-java, kotlin

For `Single` we can do like that:

```
init {
    Single.just("blah")
            .flatMapCompletable { updateLocalization() }
}

private fun updateLocalization(): Completable {
    return textsManager.getCurrentLocalization()
        .doOnSuccess {
            _localization = it
            logger.debug("updateLocalization:doOnSuccess")
        }
        .toCompletable()
}
```

And what about method like `Observable.flatMapCompletable(completable)`? Is there any reason why it isn't implemented in rxjava? How can I implement it on my own?

For now I use `Completable.await()` in `Observable.onNext`:

```
textsManager.eventsBus.observe()
        .ofType(TextsManager.Event.LocalizationUpdated::class.java)
        .doOnNext { updateLocalization().await() }
        .subscribe()
```

Comment: You mean [this](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapCompletable(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) ?

Comment: @akarnokd yeah, it's RxJava2 docs, but I use the first version in this project.

Comment: You can achieve the same effect with flatMap( v -> completable.toObservable()).toCompletable() and you can even make it as an extension method as flatMapCompletable.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks, I will try it.